# What is the expected value of $S^2_n=(n-1)^{-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar X_n)^2$

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Let $X_1,...,X_n\sim$Poiss($\lambda$) i.i.d. and $S^2_n=(n-1)^{-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar X_i)^2$ where $\bar X_n={1\over n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i$

How would you calculate $\Bbb E[S_n^2]$ the expected value of $S_n^2$?

I would show you what I tried but I have no idea how to do this

Comment: That $E(S_n^2)$ equals $\sigma^2$ where $\sigma^2$ is the population variance is a popular result. See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/100050) answer.

Comment: So the sample variance is an unbiased estimator of Poisson mean $\lambda.$ Also, for all but tiny $\lambda$ and $n,$ $(n-1)S^2/\lambda$ is approximately $\mathsf{Chisq}(n-1)$, which provides a CI for $\lambda.$ **However,** the sample mean $\bar X$ is also unbiased for $\lambda,$ has a smaller variance than $S^2,$ and hence gives shorter CIs of a given confidence level.